# ruby axlsx gem: assign formula to axlsx worksheet without using add-row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx

According to the official examples, it is possible to assign formulas to sheets during add_row https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/examples/example.rb#L355

My question is is it possible to assign formulas to columns when the table is filled up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of adding a formula to an existing cell.

```
pk = Axlsx::Package.new
wb = pk.workbook
sheet = wb.add_worksheet(name: 'Test')
sheet.add_row(['First', 'Second', 'Third'])
sheet.add_row([1, 1, 1])
sheet.add_row([2, 2, 2])
sheet.add_row([3, 3, 0])    # we will be updating the last cell in this row (C4)
sheet.add_row([4, 4, 4])

cell = sheet['C4']
cell.type = :string         # it is important to ensure the type of the cell is set before adding the formula
cell.value = '=A3+A4'

pk.serialize("example.xlsx")
```

Here is an example to dynamically update the cell formula:

```
pk = Axlsx::Package.new
wb = pk.workbook
sheet = wb.add_worksheet(name: 'Test')
sheet.add_row(['First', 'Second', 'Third'])
sheet.add_row([1, 1, 1])
sheet.add_row([2, 2, 2])
sheet.add_row([3, 3, 3])
sheet.add_row([4, 4, 4])

cells = sheet["C2:C5"]  # select an array of cells

cells.each do |cell|
  row_index = cell.row.index + 1
  cell.type = :string
  cell.value = "=SUM(A#{row_index}:B#{row_index})"
end

pk.serialize("example2.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know if it's possible to assign the formulas to the whole column. So in your case, all C columns will be the addition of corresponding A and B columns